# Write multiple objects obtained via Get-ChildItem into HTML

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to write a script that would create a list of .txt and .pdf files located in a given directory with some information about it. Using Get-ChildItem I can get the result I want, but I cannot convert it into HTML, because while doing so I lose all the information about the file (only file's name remains). With this code I can get the needed information only for the last file:

```
$types = @("*.txt", "*.pdf")
foreach ($type in $types) {
  Get-ChildItem C:\POWERSHELL -Filter $type -Recurse | ConvertTo-Html |
  Out-File c:\status23.html
}
```

With this code I only receive the names:

```
$result = {
  foreach ($type in $types) {
    Get-ChildItem C:\POWERSHELL -Filter $type 
  }
}

ConvertTo-HTML -Body "$result" -Title "htmlname" | Out-File c:\status343t4.html
```

Hope anyone can help me - how can I get all the needed info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your first example will overwrite the TXT listing with the PDF listing - probably not what you want.

Instead, collect all of the files, then selectively output the properties you want from the collection to HTML.

```
$types=@("*.txt", "*.pdf")
$myfiles = @();
foreach($type in $types){
    $myFiles += Get-ChildItem C:\POWERSHELL -Filter $type -Recurse 
}

$myfiles | ConvertTo-Html -property fullname,lastwritetime,length | out-file c:\status23.html;
```