# Open a file from an HTML file created in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I have a script in PowerShell that creates an HTML file with the list of files of specific types (e.g. ".txt") with some basic information about them. Now I wanted to add a feature that one could click the filename in the HTML page created by the script in order to open it. Could anyone at least give a hint on how to do it? This is the current output I receive (I blurred the text though):
[image: How my current output looks like]

Here is the script I'm using (from alroc's answer to this question: [Write multiple objects obtained via get-ChildItem into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911713/write-multiple-objects-obtained-via-get-childitem-into-html)):

```
$types=@("*.txt", "*.pdf")
$myfiles = @();
foreach($type in $types){
    $myFiles += Get-ChildItem C:\POWERSHELL -Filter $type -Recurse 
}

$myfiles | ConvertTo-Html -property fullname,lastwritetime,length | out-file c:\status23.html;
```

Comment: btw, we might help you better if you also show the powershell script.

Comment: I made the image clearer. The powershell script is just like the one that mr. alroc posted in my other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911713/write-multiple-objects-obtained-via-get-childitem-into-html Unfortunatelly all my other modifications didn't result in anything good :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a clickable link to the file, you need to use this kind of HTML tag:

```
<a href='file:///filename'>Display Text</a>`
```

However, if you want to change the HTML, you can't use **ConvertTo-Html** as in the script you're referencing, because that cmdlet will escape any input you provide it, so you need to create the HTML yourself. For a simple table, it's not that hard, and it lets you have more control over what the output will look like.

Try this (I've compacted your code in addition to adding the HTML output):

```
$output = "<html>`n<table>`n<tr><th align='left'>Full Name</th><th align='left'>Last Write Time</th><th align='right'>Size (bytes)</th></tr>`n"
Get-ChildItem '*.txt','*.ps1' -Recurse | %{
  $output += "<tr><td><a href='file:///$($_.FullName)'>$($_.FullName)</a></td><td>$($_.LastWriteTime)</td><td align='right'>$($_.Length)</td></tr>`n"
}
$output += "</table>`n</html>"
$output | Out-File status23.html
```

A few notes:

- You don't have to worry about HTML-escaping the interpolated values, because none of the properties you're including (FullName, LastWriteTime, Length) can contain any characters that need to be escaped in HTML.
- The `` `n ``s aren't strictly necessary, they just make the resultant HTML file more readable; the page would be rendered the same if you left them out.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you need to wrap them in an html href tag with a path to the file.

If they have access to that txt file, and they are using a browser to view the html file, the text file will open within the browser when clicked.

Example:

```
$file="C:\test\to.txt"

"<HTML><a href=`"$file`">$file</a></HTML>" | Out-file "C:\test\test.html"
```

Comment: but the thing is it may not only be an .txt file but .pdf or .doc

Comment: Regardless of the extension, the browser handles opening the file based on how it is configured.  If it is a PDF, then the browser should launch the pdf reader if that's what it is set to do.

Comment: Note that you can't just use a filename as an href value. The href must be a valid URL, which is either relative to the current page, or begins with a valid scheme identifier. For a file on the local filesystem, that's `file:///`. Using a Windows path by itself as an href value would result in links that give errors complaining that "C" isn't a valid protocol, or something like that.

Comment: File:/// is the proper prefix.  But chrome and IE seem to handle the above example just fine, they add the file:/// automatically.  Still, its probably best to put it in the href as Adi mentions.

Comment: IE and Chrome do add `file:///` if they recognize a Windows filename, but FireFox balks, and possibly other browsers would. In any case, it's safer to follow the standards than rely on implementation-specific corrections.